# Filter large array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using Mongo 3.4.10, and can not upgrade now.

I have a "left join" that need to be filtered (And in 3.4 I can't use [uncorrelated sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)).
For now, I use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html#definition) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html#exp._S_filter), but this fail on large arrays (more than 2000 elements).

I tried to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) just after the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) as recommended in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724785/aggregate-lookup-total-size-of-documents-in-matching-pipeline-exceeds-maximum-d/45726501#45726501) but I can't manage to also get my primary elements that doesn't have a secondary.

My schema is as follow :

- A primary collection (let's call it 'primary'), with ids, and some more useful fields.
- A secondary collection, with link to the primary, which can contain a lot of elements for the same primary id. Most of them are irrelevants.
- Let's suppose that for each primary id, I have one or none relevant element in the secondary collection. If there is more, I would like to use the last one (Element have a timestamp field), but this can be overlooked for now.

Here is the first solution I used :

```
return db.primary.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            'id':{
                $in:queryParam.ids
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from:'secondary',
            localField:'id',
            foreignField:'primary_id',
            as:'secondaries'
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            relevantSecondary:{
                $arrayElemAt:[
                    {
                        $filter:{
                            input:'secondaries',
                            as:'secondary',
                            cond:{
                                $eq:[
                                    '$$secondary.relevant',
                                    'true'
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            },
        }
    }
]);
```

This work nice, giving me the excepted results.
Problem appear when I have a big number of elements in secondary for a given primary id.
I get

> "Total size of documents in secondary matching { $match: { $and: [ { primary_id: { $eq: \"XXXXX\" } }, {} ] } } exceeds maximum document size"

Here is what I tried, using $unwind first :

```
return db.primary.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            'id':{
                $in:queryParam.ids
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from:'secondary',
            localField:'id',
            foreignField:'primary_id',
            as:'secondaries'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$secondaries',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    'secondaries.relevant': {$eq: 'true'}
                },
                {
                    'secondaries': []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]);
```

This work on large arrays, but I can't any more get the primary elements that doesn't have a matching secondary.

Any clue on how to make this request ?

I know the real solution would be to move to Mongo 4.0 but this is not an option in my context.

*EDIT:* Included @Fanpark suggestion to get primary with no secondary.
Problem is that this still does not return primary that have only irrelevant secondary.

Comment: Your `$match` should be this `{ '$match': {
 '$or': [
  { 'secondaries.relevant': { '$eq': 'true' } },
  { 'secondaries': [] }
 ]
}}` But I think even you have to use `$group` to reconstruct the `$unwind`ed array.

Comment: @Fanpark The problem is that this match only the primary that have no secondary at all, but I struggle to get the ones that have only irrelevant secondaries. I don't need to re-group the array as I have only one relevant element.

Comment: You can do this way `{ '$match': {
 '$or': [
  { 'secondaries.relevant': { '$eq': 'true' } },
  { $expr: { '$gte': [{ $size: '$secondaries' }, 0] }}
 ]
}}`

Comment: Sadly, $expr is only available in mongo 3.6 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500536/mongodb-unknown-top-level-operator-expr-nodejs But I'm tr<ing to find a way around.

Comment: This give me every primary that have a secondary, but not the relevant one. I am kind of hopeless on this, and trying other way (by combining 2 queries), but without luck for now.